# Await HttpClient and do-while loop

Tags: c#, loops, post, async-await, do-while

I have a method to POST some data to server. Server may return aswer means I need change URL and send data to other server. I use for it `HttpClient` class from 4.5 framework. I use either do-while loop to repeat requests until I do not need redirecton. But there is a problem.

The question is why if I create `HttpClient` instance outside loop, second `await` didn't happen and my programm get out of loop, but if I create `HttpClient` instance inside the loop again and again - all is fine? Can I reuse one `HttpClient` for several POST requsts inside do-while loop inside async method?

My working code sample:

```
public async Task<bool> GameLogin()
{
    JToken r;
    do
    {
        var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            CookieContainer = this.myCContainer,
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
        };
        var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("client-ver", Versoin);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("method", "SignIn");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authKey", AppParams["auth_key"].ToString());

        var content = new StringContent(this.SendStr);

        var answer = await client.PostAsync(this.CurrentUrl, content);
        var rawString = await answer.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        DinamicData = JObject.Parse(rawString);
        r = DinamicData["r"];
        if (r == null) continue;
        this.CurrentUrl = string.Format("http://{0}/main.ashx", r);
    } while (r != null);

    return DinamicData.Type != JTokenType.Null;
}
```

My did not working code sample:

```
public async Task<bool> GameLogin()
{
    var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        CookieContainer = this.myCContainer,
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
    };
    var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("client-ver", Versoin);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("method", "SignIn");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authKey", AppParams["auth_key"].ToString());

    var content = new StringContent(this.SendStr);

    JToken r;
    do
    {
        var answer = await client.PostAsync(this.CurrentUrl, content);
        var rawString = await answer.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        DinamicData = JObject.Parse(rawString);
        r = DinamicData["r"];
        if (r == null) continue;
        this.CurrentUrl = string.Format("http://{0}/main.ashx", r);
    } while (r != null);

    return DinamicData.Type != JTokenType.Null;
}
```

And my second code did not wait `await` in secont loop turn.

Comment: Well you say it didn't wait - what *did* happen? Was there an exception?

Comment: Note that when you reuse the same HttpClient, you're effectively in one session - which could definitely affect how authentication etc is handled. It would be useful to look at what's happening at the HTTP level, e.g. with WireShark.

Comment: I did not get `answer`. My app gets out of do-while and out of `GameLogin` method

Comment: It would only "not get" `answer` if an exception occurred. Otherwise *some* value has to be returned. (I assume you're awaiting the return value of `GameLogin`, of course...) Please provide more information - it's very hard to help you at the moment.

Comment: Exception! Of course! How can I forget? Yes, now I have much more info. It says that I "Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.Http.StringContent'.". This is answer! Thank you!!

Comment: Right - I've added an answer on the basis of that information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, now we've got the exception...

I suspect the problem isn't reusing the `HttpClient` - it's reusing this:

```
var content = new StringContent(this.SendStr);
```

I suspect that `content` is probably being disposed by the `HttpClient`'s *first* call, which makes the second call fail.

Just move that line inside the loop (it's inside the loop in your working code), and I expect all will be well.